# How to get all possible combinations for n arrays with different number of elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, combinations

I have some number of arrays which is unknown at programming time, maybe it is 3 or 4 or 7 ... each array has some elements, i.e,

```
a={1 2 3 4}
b={6 7 5 2 1}
c={22 4 6 8 4 8 5 4}
d={....}
e, f, g, ...
```

I want to get get all possible combinations by sampling one number from each array for example one case is that I pick up "1" from a, "7" from b, first "8" from c, d[3], e[5],... to make "1,7,8,d[3],e[5],...". It's not possible to use nested for loops because I don't know the number of arrays at compile time. If it was known for example 4 arrays (a,b,c,d) I could use 4 loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length-1; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; i <= b.Length-1; j++)
   {
      for (int k = 0; i <= c.Length-1; k++)
      {
         for (int m = 0; i <= d.Length-1; m++)
         {
            Response[f++] = a[i].toString()+","+b[j].toString()+","+c[k].toString()+","+d[m].toString();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

but for different number of arrays, I don't have any idea.

Comment: why don't you use a two-dimentional array instead ? and use a DFS method to generate combination

Comment: @Rawling - This is not a duplicate. This question has a variable number of inputs. The other question is restricted to only three input arrays.

Comment: @Enigmativity The answer to that question generalized to this solution.

Comment: @Rawling - I'm sorry, I didn't see recursion in that answer. I see it now. My mistake. Nevertheless, I like my answer better. :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity That's fair enough, I think you're right anyway in that the *question* isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved...I changed it according to my desire, nevertheless I couldn't realize its algorithm! is it possible for any one who also answer this quaestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094602/how-to-calculate-a-quadratic-function-of-n-variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
Func<
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>,
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> f0 = null;
f0 = xss =>
{
    if (!xss.Any())
    {
        return new [] { Enumerable.Empty<int>() };
    }
    else
    {
        var query =
            from x in xss.First()
            from y in f0(xss.Skip(1))
            select new [] { x }.Concat(y);
        return query;
    }
};

Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>, IEnumerable<string>> f =
    xss => f0(xss).Select(xs => String.Join(",", xs));
```

So if I have this input:

```
var input = new []
{
    new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, },
    new [] { 6, 7, 5, 2, 1, },
    new [] { 22, 4, 6, 8, 4, 8, 5, 4, },
};
```

I can get the results this way:

```
var results = f(input);
```

[image: results]

---

Here's a version which simply sums the results, as per the request in the comments:

```
Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>, IEnumerable<int>> f = null;
f = xss =>
{
    if (!xss.Any())
    {
        return new [] { 0 };
    }
    else
    {
        var query =
            from x in xss.First()
            from y in f(xss.Skip(1))
            select x + y;
        return query;
    }
};

var input = new []
{
    new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, },
    new [] { 6, 7, 5, 2, 1, },
    new [] { 22, 4, 6, 8, 4, 8, 5, 4, },
};

var results = f(input);
```

Comment: actually the response is not a string, I wrote it as an example! response is a mathematical function... you may assume it like response= a+b+c+d+.... Am I able to use this method for that purpose?!

Comment: As in you just want to sum all the values?! Please include an example of what output you're looking for?!

Comment: no! for two vector a , b it is as follows:
response=constant1*a+constant2*b+constant3*a*b+constant4*a^2+constant5*b^2+constant6;
for three vector a, b, c it is as follows:
response=constant1*a+constant2*b+constant3*c+constant4*a*b+constant5*a*c+constant6*b*c+constant7*a^2+constant8*b^2+constant9*c^2+constant10;

Comment: @user3636337 - I've added a summing version to my answer. But it seems like it isn't even as simple as summing the values. I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was solved...I changed it according to my desire, nevertheless I couldn't realize its algorithm! is it possible for you one to also answer this quaestion: stackoverflow.com/questions/24094602/

Answer (score 2):

I think the linq version looks awesome:

```
from i in a
from j in b
from k in c
from m in d
select String.Join(",", i, j, k, m)
```

But the answer to your question is not easy.
Eric Lippert wrote about it on his blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Comment: actually the response is not a string, I wrote it as an example! response is a mathematical function... you may assume it like response= a+b+c+d.... Am I able to use this method for that purpose?!

Comment: Sure. The from's and the CartesianProduct just return an IEnumerable. Just change the select statement to select what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The following extension method imitates a nested stack of `foreach` loops:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void ForEachNested<T>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sources,
        Action<IEnumerable<T>> action)
    {
        var enumerables = sources.ToArray();
        Stack<IEnumerator<T>> fe = new Stack<IEnumerator<T>>();
        fe.Push(enumerables[0].GetEnumerator());

        while (fe.Count > 0)
        {
            if (fe.Peek().MoveNext())
            {
                if (fe.Count == enumerables.Length)
                    action(new Stack<T>(fe.Select(e => e.Current)));
                else
                    fe.Push(enumerables[fe.Count].GetEnumerator());
            }
            else
            {
                fe.Pop().Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could use it as follows:

```
new[] { a, b, c, d }.ForEachNested(e => { Response[f++] = string.Join(",", e); });
```

or, to do your maths,

```
new[] { a, b, c, d }.ForEachNested(e => { Response[f++] = e.Sum(); });
```

This has the advantage of not performing hundreds of array allocations.

Ordinarily I'd shy away from using a LINQ-like method to *act* rather than *query* but as this is closely imitating how a `foreach` loop works I don't mind so much.

Comment: I have one problems with that, the declarations has no errors but when I use it, i define four vectors a,b,c,d...and construct an array of these vectors but the "e" parameter of function ForEachNested(...) is unrecognizable